# How can find "roots" of named branches in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I use the following every week or so to create a new branch named `foobar` that is branched from my current working directory, which could be *any* named branch.  Let's say I do this for a year.

I will have several branches name "foobar" that was created from many different branches and the commit text is random.

How can I find all of these "roots" (the commit after the `hg branch foobar` is ran)

```
PS D:\Test> hg summ
parent: 33670:fd440a61dce2
 AD: fix case 15578
branch: SomeRandomBranchName
commit: (clean)
update: (current)

PS D:\Test> hg branch foobar
marked working directory as branch foobar
PS D:\Test> hg ci -m "Some Random String"
PS D:\Test> hg summ
parent: 33676:dbb7b123f05f tip
 create foobar
branch: foobar
commit: (clean)
update: (current)
phases: 1 draft

PS D:\Test>
```

Comment: The revspec for roots (commits whose parents are not in the set) of a set is `roots`, so `roots(foobar)` should suffice

Comment: Almost, it has to be `roots(branch(foobar))`. `foobar` refers to the most recent commit on the branch, not all changesets in the branch.

Comment: @ReimerBehrends: aha. Oops, it's been a while since I've actually been using Mercurial day-to-day... You should probably turn that into an answer.